# AWS CloudFormation - Calculate IP from FQDN passed in through parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want users to pass in a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) that doesn't necessarily have to be a part of the AWS cloud. I'm requesting a FQDN to be more user friendly (I know asking for an IP would make this very simple). I want to take this FQDN, calculate it's IP, and use that IP in a security group ingress CidrIp property.

How do I calculate the IP?

My Parameter

```
Parameters:
  FQDN: 
    Type: String   #Pass in FQDN as a String
    Description: The Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) of your server
```

My Security Group

```
SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    DependsOn: Subnet
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security Group governing ingress and egress rules.
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 8443
          ToPort: 8443
          CidrIp: <IP of FQDN>/32
```

Comment: This is a misguided attempt to be "helpful."  Security groups work against IP addresses and that is the correct thing you should be asking for.  Any user that doesn't know what IP to give you isn't going to be any better-informed when it comes to providing a correct FQDN for whatever purpose you need, and is likely to answer that question incorrectly... not to mention the fact that FQDN ⇄ IP address cannot properly be assumed to be 1:1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using a Lambda-backed Custom Resource, the lambda would take in the FQDN parameter, determine the IP and then return it to be referenced in the Security Group Resource.

As an example, here's how the CloudFormation could look (using SAM for this particular example):

```yaml
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  FQDN:
    Type: String

Resources:
  GetIpFromFqdnFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: main.handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      CodeUri: ./

  GetIpFromFqdn:
    Type: Custom::GetIpFromFqdn
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt GetIpFromFqdnFunction.Arn
      FQDN: !Ref FQDN

  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: SG allowing IP from given FQDN
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: !Sub ${GetIpFromFqdn}/32
```

And the lambda could look something like this using crhelper to handle the events

```py
from crhelper import CfnResource
import socket

helper = CfnResource()

def handler(event, context):
    helper(event, context)


@helper.create
@helper.update
def get_ip_from_fqdn(event, _):
    fqdn = event['ResourceProperties']['FQDN']
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(fqdn)

    return ip


@helper.delete
def no_op(_, _):
    pass
```

Comment: This was a valid answer to my question. However, it added more complexity to my setup than I desired. I decided to just ask for the IP instead. Thanks for the suggestion!